# I can't seem to echo without quotation marks around my string

Tags: shell-script, string, printing

I'm trying the following form in a .sh script:

```
echo 'string' $var >> print.dat
```

and it prints the following:

```
'string' 14.27
```

Which is almost what I want, but I need the quotation marks to disappear. All I need is:

```
string 14.27
```

does anyone know the solution here? I'm sure it's a simple question but I searched around and I couldn't find what I wanted. Maybe I just didn't know what exactly to search for.

EDIT:

I appreciate all your help and hate to admit it, but I was making a really foolish mistake all along. Things were printing the way I wanted all along in print.dat, but I was using sh -x to view the output and thus I saw quotations around my strings.

Comment: What Unix and shell are you using?

Comment: I'm not really sure. But I'm using ssh/putty to reach a cluster.

Comment: Distributor ID: RedHatEnterpriseServer
Description:    Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.5 (Santiago)
Release:        6.5
Codename:       Santiago

Comment: Any alias or shell function called `echo`?

Comment: Are you really sure you have plain single quotes? Is it possible you have some fancy "smart" quotes? What code editor do you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo 'string' $var >print.dat
```

This would not display anything, but write `string` followed by the value of `$var` (possibly undergoing some transformations as it's not quoted) to the file `print.dat`. The quotes around the string will be removed.

Make sure you don't have `echo` aliased to anything.  To bypass any alias or shell function with the same name, use

```
command echo 'string' $var >print.dat
```

or use `/bin/echo` in place of `echo`.

You may also use `printf` which is usually more portable than `echo`:

```
printf 'string %s\n' "$var" >print.dat
```

Comment: I was using >>. I'll make sure to edit my question

Answer (score 0):

This workaround may do the job (backslashify the backtick ` according to your shell):

```
echo 'string' $var | tr -d \' >> print.dat
```

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work. I get:  'string' 14.27       then on the next line tr -d ''\'''

Comment: I think that was because I copied the ">>>" from your question which was wrong. With the ">>" it ought to work. `tr -d` deletes the characters it is given from the stream.